# Have the potential therapeutic applications of cell fusion between cancer cells and neural cells been investigated?

Tags: cancer, medicine, literature, neuron, biomedical-engineering

Studies have appeared on the possible role that cell fusion plays in the formation of certain cancers. For instance, Sitar et al. (2019) have [looked into](https://www.haematologica.org/article/view/1509/6705) the process of cell fusion in the formation of erythroleukemia.

However, research has also been done on the potential therapeutic effects of cell fusion to tumour immunotheraphy, see e.g. this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3187729/#B13) by Pedrazzoli et al. (2011) and [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3187729/#B13) by Sullivan and Eggan (2006). For instance, in the former an [article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7507262/) by Guo et al. (1994) is mentioned in which researchers fused B-cells with carcinoma hepatoma cells to create a vaccine, which resulted in hybrid cells that lost their tumorigenicity and became immunogenic.

I am interested in a particular type of heterotypic cell fusion. More specifically, I am curious whether biomedical research has been done on the potential therapeutic applications of fusion between neurons and different types of cancer cells. My reasoning is as follows: neurons in the brain do not renew themselves through cell division processes that occur in many other parts of the body. So if neural cells fuse with cancer cells (that grow and divide more quickly than normal cells), the resulting hybrid cell might have lost some of its carcinoid properties - including its tendency towards rapid proliferation.

**Question**: has any research been done on the potential therapeutic applications of cell fusion between neural cells and cancer cells? If so, can you point me towards a relevant reference?

*Note 1*: I am a mathematican, not a biomedical/pharmaceutical scientist or a biologist. If my reasoning seems seriously flawed, please enlighten me on the matter. I did try to perform a literature review and hope this question is appropriate for this venue.

*Note 2*: This [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31774/have-the-potential-therapeutic-applications-of-cell-fusion-between-cancer-cells) was also asked on Medical Sciences Beta SE a few months ago. A user on that venue suggested I'd ask it over here, as s/he asserted there are more experts related to the field on this SE page.

Comment: This is a site for questions about biology, whereas yours is about history, at best, or an attempt to start a discussion, at worst.

Comment: @David I've added the "Literature" tag to make it clear this question is a reference request. If no papers on the topic exist, an answer explaining the plausible reasons behind that would suffice from my point of view.

Comment: Tags do not determine suitability of questions for SE Biology. Any User with a certain reputation can invent a new tag. The description of the purpose of the site in the [Tour] and the Help on asking questions does. That makes it clear that this is a question and answer site about problems in biology. A reference request is not a problem in biology.

Comment: @David I think the question is okay, it shows some prior research, though like any similar question it's far harder to provide an answer that says "no, this idea doesn't make a lot of sense" that fits our site guidelines.